# Hyperledger Fabric transaction are taking longer time to commit

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have configured hyperledger fabric 1.4 network with 2 organizations with 2 peers under each organization(1 endorsing peer) and 3 orderer. In my configtx.yaml file transaction related parameter are configured as below

```
OrdererType: etcdraft 

Addresses:
    - orderer1.example.com:7050
    - orderer2.example.com:7050
    - orderer3.example.com:7050

BatchTimeout: 2s

BatchSize:

    MaxMessageCount: 10

    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB

    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
```

previously for commiting the transaction and creating a block it used to take 1-2 seconds but from last week I'm observing it is taking more than 15 seconds. can any one suggest what would be the issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: What is the value FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC defined for you peers? Does everything run on the same VM or on several VMs?

Comment: In my peer CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL is defined as DEBUG. and I have multinode setup each peer is running on different VM.

Comment: At least in my case I had problems with the hard drive. You can check how much place is left on your hard drive. In case of FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG all the smallest logs are written to the hard drive and can completely fill up the hard drive in days or weeks (depends on the size). If there is really not a lot place left, you can clean up the present docker logs and restart your containers.

Comment: there are enough space on VMs and I restarted my containers but still getting same issue

Comment: If you do not set the docker log separately, it cannot be considered a problem as 100MB.

Comment: It seems that more detailed information is needed. It is necessary to check in which section of the transaction flow the bottleneck occurs. chaincode invoke -> peer chaincode endorsing / transfer to orderer / orderer packaging block / transfer to peer / validation check -> commit transaction. Can you determine where the bottleneck is occurring?

Comment: It would be nice to measure it accurately based on the code, but you can simply check where the bottleneck occurs through the `docker logs <container_name> -f` command.

Comment: Also, if you are using couchdb as the state db, you need to check for slow queries. Can you check if it takes a long time when querying couchdb through curl? If it takes a long time with the curl command, this is an issue with couchdb and has nothing to do with fabric.

Comment: @myeongkilkim I checked the logs till transfer to orderer it is fine but taking time for packaging the block and sending back to peer.

Comment: And I'm using LevelDB